# Initializer with self.variable = variable

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift. I don't understand what's the purpose of **self.seconds = seconds** in the following example:

```
class Time {
    var seconds:Double = 0

    init(seconds: Double) {
        self.seconds = seconds
    }

    var minutes: Double {
        get {
            return (seconds / 60)
        }
        set {
            self.seconds = (newValue * 60)
        }
    }

    var hours: Double {
        get {
            return (seconds / (60 * 60))
        }
        set {
            self.seconds = (newValue * (60 * 60))
        }
    }
}
```

According to xcode 'self.seconds' is a variable and 'seconds' is a let constant. I'm confused. Any thoughts ?

Comment: it assigns the initializer parameter to the field variable of the same name

Comment: I still don't really understand, as the variable has already been initialized

Comment: so what? You can always overwrite its value, the line is not necessary but it just is there.

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of you initializer, you have one local constant `seconds` and a variable property `seconds` (which you are accessing with `self.seconds` to avoid confusions).

To make it less confusing, you could rename the parameter of your initializer to something like `newSeconds`.

```
init(seconds newSeconds: Double) {
    self.seconds = newSeconds
}
```

This doesn't change how you call the initializer (you still use the label `seconds:`, but your initializer is less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a Time object, you store the seconds you pass in as an argument into the member variable (also called seconds). You can imagine if you had another initializer for minutes or hours, it would convert the minutes or hours and then store them as seconds. So for example:

```
class Time {
    var seconds:Double = 0

    init(seconds: Double) {
        self.seconds = seconds
    }

    init(minutes: Double) {
        self.seconds = minutes * 60
    }

    init(hours: Double) {
        self.seconds = hours * 60 * 60
    }

    var minutes: Double {
        get {
            return (seconds / 60)
        }
        set {
            self.seconds = (newValue * 60)
        }
    }

    var hours: Double {
        get {
            return (seconds / (60 * 60))
        }
        set {
            self.seconds = (newValue * (60 * 60))
        }
    }
}
```

Just because the parameter has the same name as the Time object's variable, doesn't mean it automatically contains the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options when passing a non-optional parameter:

- You declare the property with a default value and overwrite it in `init` (not recommended):

  ```
  var seconds : Double = 0.0 // or even var seconds = 0.0 (the compiler infers the Double type)

  init(seconds: Double) {
      self.seconds = seconds
  }
  ```
- You declare the property and assign the default value in `init`:

  ```
  var seconds : Double

  init(seconds: Double) {
      self.seconds = seconds
  }
  ```
- You declare the property as **constant** (read only) and assign the value in `init`

  ```
  let seconds : Double

  init(seconds: Double) {
      self.seconds = seconds
  }
  ```

In any case `self.seconds` represents the property and `seconds` the passed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate `Time` the init method is called. `var seconds:Double = 0` defines a default value.

```
let time = Time()  //calls init(). time has default value of zero seconds
```

If you call one of the parametrized init methods the default value gets overridden:

```
let time = Time(seconds: 42.0) //calls init(seconds: Double). time has been initialized with 42 seconds
```